# JavaScript DOM Error in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, dom

I'm receiving the following error on this line of code

```
select.up().appendChild(sw);
```

With error "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'up' "

This only happens in Internet Explorer...  Chrome, Safari, and Firefox all run the code fine.  I'm unable to find anything via Google searching for "select.up()". This code isn't my own and I'm not very adept with using DOM in Javascript.

Here is rest of the code:

```
<?php 
$swatches = $this->get_option_swatches();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
        try {
            var swatches = <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($swatches); ?>;

            function find_swatch(key, value) {
                for (var i in swatches) {
                    if (swatches[i].key == key && swatches[i].value == value)
                        return swatches[i];
                }
                return null;
            }

            function has_swatch_key(key) {
                for (var i in swatches) {
                    if (swatches[i].key == key)
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            function create_swatches(label, select) {
                // create swatches div, and append below the <select>
                var sw = new Element('div', {'class': 'swatches-container'});
                select.up().appendChild(sw);

                // store these element to use later for recreate swatches
                select.swatchLabel = label;
                select.swatchElement = sw;

                // hide select
                select.setStyle({position: 'absolute', top: '-9999px'})

                $A(select.options).each(function(opt, i) {
                    if (opt.getAttribute('value')) {
                        var elm;
                        var key = trim(opt.innerHTML);

                        // remove price
                        if (opt.getAttribute('price')) key = trim(key.replace(/\+([^+]+)$/, ''));

                        var item = find_swatch(label, key);
                        if (item)
                            elm = new Element('img', {
                                src: '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA); ?>swatches/'+item.img, 
                                alt: opt.innerHTML, 
                                title: opt.innerHTML, 
                                'class': 'swatch-img'});
                        else {
                            console.debug(label, key, swatches);
                            elm = new Element('a', {'class': 'swatch-span'});
                            elm.update(opt.innerHTML);
                        }
                        elm.observe('click', function(event) {
                            select.selectedIndex = i;
                            fireEvent(select, 'change');
                            var cur = sw.down('.current');
                            if (cur) cur.removeClassName('current');
                            elm.addClassName('current');
                        });
                        sw.appendChild(elm);
                    }
                });
            }

            function recreate_swatches_recursive(select) {
                // remove the old swatches
                if (select.swatchElement) {
                    select.up().removeChild(select.swatchElement);
                    select.swatchElement = null;
                }

                // create again
                if (!select.disabled)
                    create_swatches(select.swatchLabel, select);

                // recursively recreate swatches for the next select
                if (select.nextSetting)
                    recreate_swatches_recursive(select.nextSetting);
            }

            function fireEvent(element,event){
                if (document.createEventObject){
                    // dispatch for IE
                    var evt = document.createEventObject();
                    return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
                }
                else{
                    // dispatch for firefox + others
                    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
                    evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
                    return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
                }
            }

            function trim(str) {
                return str.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
            }


            $$('#product-options-wrapper dt').each(function(dt) {

                // get custom option's label
                var label = '';
                $A(dt.down('label').childNodes).each(function(node) {
                    if (node.nodeType == 3) label += node.nodeValue;
                });
                label = trim(label);

                var dd = dt.next();
                var select = dd.down('select');
                if (select && has_swatch_key(label)) {
                    create_swatches(label, select);

                    // if configurable products, recreate swatches of the next select when the current select change
                    if (select.hasClassName('super-attribute-select')) {
                        select.observe('change', function() {
                            recreate_swatches_recursive(select.nextSetting);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch(e) {
            alert("Color Swatches javascript error. Please report this error to support@ikova.com. Error:" + e.message);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Appreciate any insight anyone could give me!

Comment: The [`up()` method](http://prototypejs.org/api/element/up) appears to come from Prototype.

Comment: That code looks like it's written to use a library, maybe Prototype. Is that so?  If so, there are several things about it that are pretty questionable and likely to cause problems in IE: "hasClassName()", "observe()", etc. Hard to tell for sure however.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall ah OK I couldn't recall.  Well it *might* work to add something like `select = $(select);` to the start of that function, right?  I'm a little rusty with Prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `up()` is a PrototypeJS method, so i'm pretty sure you would need it to work.

http://prototypejs.org/api/element/up

Comment: This is true - however it's also true that in IE it's necessary for all DOM element references to be "wrapped" explicitly. (At least, that was true with Prototype at some point, because in IE it's not possible to extend DOM prototypes.)

Comment: I think your suggestion of select = $(select); might do the job. Darn IE. Lets see if it works for the Op.

Comment: I tried placing `select = $(select);` right at the start of the function and I'm still receiving the same error...  Thanks for the reference to Prototype!  This code is being used in a Magento Website so Prototype is used.

Comment: Its hard to know without being knee deep inside your app. It could be anything from your script loading before prototype (making .up() unavailable) , or jsut about anything else :P

Comment: Hi Shai would Internet Explorer load prototype later than any other browser?  Because it's working fine in all the webkit browsers and firefox.  The prototype script is being loaded in the header and the DOM script is being loaded in the page. You can see an example of the page [here](http://bit.ly/zzIA6H).

Comment: You can never know with IE. Different browsers sometimes load things on a different stack, and IE is known to be problematic. Try calling some basic Prototype code at that same point and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I m also facing this problem. so, i comment

```
var sw = new Element('div', {'class': 'swatches-container'});
$(select).up().appendChild(sw);
select.setStyle({position: 'absolute', top: '-9999px'})
```

lines from function create_swatches
and paste it in function trim(str).

After this i did not error again.